# Magento1: Form Validation suddenly broken?

Tags: php, attributes, customer, javascript, customer-attribute

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem I've recently run into, whenever I attempt to create an account or checkout as a guest it keeps coming up with "The first name cannot be empty, The last name cannot be empty, Invalid email address".

As we run quite a busy store I make changes on a daily basis and can't for the life of me figure out what caused it, one change in particular matches up to the time perfectly.

I have the Clarion Customer Attributes extension installed and I set the first/last name's Input Validation to "Letters" and the email attribute to "Email". The moment I noticed the error I quickly reverted my changes (setting input validation to none) and it continued happening. Now for the life of me I can't figure out what I've triggered!

As a temporary measure I commented out the warnings themself but I'm constantly receiving notifications from paypal and our other payment provider that parts of the customers information is missing (usually email or name)

Any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see I feel that attribute entries may be removed from the "Customer Form Attribute" table in the database this table decide in which form like (register form, account edit form, checkout form) we need to use attribute.

in Magento 1.9 first name attribute id is 5 so search the entries in above table whether it exists or not.

the entries in the table are like below:

form_code              attribute_id

adminhtml_customer          5

checkout_register           5

customer_account_create     5

customer_account_edit       5

Comment: Hey, wouldn't this just remove the attribute from the specified forms?

Comment: Funnily enough, after checking the customer_form_attribute table i noticed some entries had disappeared - I restored the table from backup and that fixed the problem. Thank you very much!